# What's the best material to patch gaps between moulding and the wall?

Tags: drywall, walls, trim, baseboard, moulding

I am installing new moulding (aka baseboards, woodwork, etc).  A few of the walls sort of dip inward, so a gap is left in between the moulding and drywall.  What's a good material for patching this gap?  Would ordinary spackle do the trick or is there a better alternative?  It has to be something I can paint over.

Comment: I added the trim tag for you, maybe we should setup a synonym for moulding.

Comment: See also [what is a good method to seal a baseboard to stop an existing draft](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/42/what-is-a-good-method-to-seal-a-baseboard-to-stop-an-existing-draft)

Comment: @B Mitch - I added a synonym of "moulding" for the trim tag (still needs to get voted up though)

Comment: I think we have to tag a bunch of questions and get some experts on the topic first to be able to vote on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple job for caulk.  Just get a tube, run a bead, and smooth with your finger.  Allow to dry, and paint it the same color as the baseboard.  If the space is wide enough, first try to close the gap by nailing the moulding into the closest stud.  If the caulk shrinks too much, after it dries you can run another bead on top.

Note that spackle would crack when the baseboard moves.

Comment: I got some caulk today and will probably get around to installing the moulding at the end of the week.  Thanks to DA01 for also answering.

Answer (score 4):

paintable caulk. Spackle will crack eventually.

Comment: I like DAP painter's caulk. It's smooth, very white, low shrinkage and water soluble for easy clean up of any access on the wall.  Cheap too, usually around $2 a tube.